# Graph of $\arcsin(\cos(x))$

Tags: graphing-functions

How to draw graph of $\arcsin(\cos(x))$ or even $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ without use of graphing calculator , its sort of confusing me from long time. It gives pointed curves when drawing from calculator , why does it looks like that? Why it isn't just linear graph? Can someone shed some light here?

Comment: well, for starters, $\arcsin{(x)}$ and $\sin{(x)}$ are inverse functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the domain of the arcsin function is $[-1,1]$ and its range is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.  This is important because even though $\sin x$ and $\arcsin x$ are inverse functions, it's not correct to say that $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$ for *all* $x$.

This might explain why your graphing calculator is giving you "pointed" curves.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** 
 For the first function use the identity $$\cos(x)=\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi2\right),$$ for the second it is useful to note that $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$, since $\arcsin x$ and $\sin x$ are [inverse functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).

Also be careful about the domains and ranges of those functions, and so $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$ isn't true for all $x$.